# Pass variable of custom type to custom MSBuild task

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I've developed custom MSBuild task called **ExportSolution** and I need to pass custom `enum` **PackageType** value to it.

The **PackageType** is simple:

```cs
public enum PackageType
{
    Managed,
    Unmanaged,
    Both
}
```

The MSBuild script is simple too:

```xml
<Target Name="ExportSolution" DependsOnTargets="BuildTasksDll">
    <Message Text="Exporting solution '$(SolutionName)' to '$(SolutionPath)'" />
    <ExportSolution SolutionName="$(SolutionName)" PackageType="Both"></ExportSolution>
</Target>
```

However running script for that target I'm receiving following error message:

> error MSB4030: "Both" is an invalid value for the "PackageType" parameter of the "ExportSolution" task. The "PackageType" parameter is of type "Tasks.Common.PackageType".

In which format I should pass value to the variable of PackageType to make this code work?

Comment: Have you tried passing it as full type name, i.e. `Tasks.Common.PackateType.Both`? Other solution may be to pass it as string and then parse it inside task

Comment: @Pako I have tried such approach, there is no difference, unfortunately...

Comment: 'Both' has a value of 2, so passing '2' into the property may work.

    <ExportSolution SolutionName="$(SolutionName)" PackageType="2">

This won't be very readable, though, so I think Pako's suggestion of making the property a string and parsing it inside the task might be better.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I was surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the Enum like so.

```
public enum PackageType
{
    Managed = 0,
    Unmanaged = 1,
    Both = 2
}
```

Then I would edit my build script to use integers as the selection method.

```
 <ExportSolution SolutionName="$(SolutionName)" PackageType=2></ExportSolution>
```

This may not be the solution you are looking for, but it may work for what you need.

Comment: This might work, definitely, but this also means that I need to change interface of the class called to use bare integers instead of enumerations... I could easily delete that enum then... And there will be no clarity and readability in code anymore....